# How do I copy an instance of a class with a nested class containing a pointer member to the outer class?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, inner-classes, outer-classes

Novice C++ programmer here. Let's say I have a class Outer with a nested class Inner. Inner contains a pointer member, set during construction, to Outer. Outer contains a function AddNewInner() that creates a new Inner pointing to itself and adds it to a vector.

```
class Outer {

public:

    class Inner {
    public:
        Inner(Outer* outerParent) : mOuterParent(outerParent) {}
        Outer* mOuterParent;
    }

    void AddNewInner() {
        Inner newInner(this);
        mInnersVec.push_back(newInner);
    }

    vector<Inner> mInnersVec;
}
```

This works fine when creating a new instance of Outer and calling AddNewInner() to add Inners to the vector. However, I have run into an issue when I try to create a copy of an instance of Outer: The Outer copy's vector of Inners do not point to the copy (itself), they still point to the original Outer.

```
Outer outerA;
outerA.AddNewInner(); 
Outer* ptrA = outerA.mInnersVec[0].mOuterParent; // this points to outerA, good!

Outer outerB = outerA;
Outer* ptrB = outerB.mInnersVec[0].mOuterParent; // this still points to outerA, bad!
```

I need the vector of Inners in the copy to point to the copy, not the original. What's the best way of accomplishing this, or perhaps is there an alternate way to do the same thing?

Comment: Aah.... You need to read up on copy constructors. Google  copy constructors, deep copy, shallow copy. Lots of references out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this is expected behaviour. When you create a copy of an object in C++, the compiler uses the *copy constructor*. If you haven't written your own copy constructor for a class, then it uses the compiler-generated copy constructor, which simply runs the (possibly generated) copy constructor for each member in turn.

So when copying an `Outer`, the sequence of events goes like this:

- Compiler runs the (generated) copy constructor for `Outer`
- This runs the copy constructor for `std::vector`. This constructor assigns the storage for the new vector, and then runs the copy constructor for each element in turn
- So the (generated) copy constructor for `Inner` runs for each element, which just copies the member pointer (still pointing to the original `Outer`).

In order to update the `Inner` elements when copying an `Outer`, you need to write a custom copy constructor for `Outer` which updates the pointers as you'd like. Something like so:

```
Outer::Outer(const Outer& other)
    : mInnersVec(other.mInnersVec) // Do initial vector copy
{
    // Update vector elements
    for (auto& elem : mInnersVec) {
       elem.mOuterParent = this;
    }
}
```

Note that whenever you write a custom copy constructor, you almost always need to write a custom assignment operator too. I'd recommend reading up on copying and assignment in your favourite C++ textbook :-).

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilize a custom [copy constructor/assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) for your class. This will allow you to make a deep copy of your `Outer* mOuterParent` variable; probably creating a new one.

When you copy a pointer, you are copying a variable which points to a specific address space in memory. Copying the pointer only gives you the ability to access the same 'true variable' through two 'accessor variables'.

In your example the `Outer* mOuterParent` variable of a particular `outer` object will *always* point to the same instantiation of an `outer` class pointed to by that pointer no matter how many copies of that particular object you make.